# VirtualBox Segfault when Deleting Snapshot

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running a Ubuntu 14.04 host and a Windows 10 Guest. As I explained in a [different question on this same subject](https://superuser.com/questions/1011325/virtualbox-windows-10-guest-resizing-snapshots-and-losing-activation), I'm ultimately trying to increase the size of my Windows 10 disk so that I can install the latest Windows 10 update (Threshold 2).

I currently have 1 snapshot, and this snapshot is preventing Windows (or anything else, for that matter, such as gparted when run via live CD) from seeing the increased storage space.

I've [already tried cloning the machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1011325/virtualbox-windows-10-guest-resizing-snapshots-and-losing-activation), but Windows 10 loses its activation after I run a full clone. That's happened twice.

When I try to delete the snapshot, it takes several minutes trying to "merge the differencing..." and then fails (completely crashes). Ubuntu's message whenever an application crashes appears with "The application Oracle VM VirtualBox has closed unexpectedly"

This is the only line I see in /var/log/syslog: `Dec 15 05:52:20 Develop-CENTS kernel: [ 2082.315873] DeleteSnap[6852]: segfault at 20 ip 00000000006e3eab sp 00007f8c97893888 error 4 in VBoxSVC[400000+45b000]`

Is there anything that I can do, or is this a bug that I should just report to the VirtualBox developers?

Comment: Afraid I can't answer the segfault issue, but I'm curious as to what happened when you tried to reactivate after cloning? Usually when this happens I just use the automated phone line number and it reactivates without an issue?

Comment: That's a good thought, but not needed now. I'm answering my question here in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some help on the VirtualBox mailing list.

The reason that I was unable to delete the snapshot is directly related to the reason why Windows wasn't seeing the increased disk space (see my other question that I linked to). It's because I had resized the base disk .vdi file, but did NOT resize the snapshot .vdi file.

Once I resized the snapshot .vdi file, I confirmed Windows 10 can now see the increased disk space. I also successfully deleted the snapshot.

Hope this helps someone!